# I have a dataframe and want to fill all empty column values based on previous rows with identical values based in another column?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe shown below. I want to copy a column value from previous row where the same value is present ('Name').

```
df: 

Name    Age   Ethnicity
Sam     17    E
Chris   0     B
Tom     19    P
Sam     22    NaN
Chris   18    NaN
Tom     7     NaN
```

And This is what I want:

```
Name    Age   Ethnicity
Sam     17    E
Chris   0     B
Tom     19    P
Sam     22    E
Chris   18    B
Tom     7     P
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try conditional fill

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
["Sam" ,    17 ,   "E"],
["Chris" ,  0  ,   "B"],
["Tom"  ,   19  ,  "P"],
["Sam"  ,   22  ,  np.nan],
["Chris" ,  18  ,  np.nan],
["Tom"  ,   7  ,   np.nan],
              
] ,columns=['Name', "Age", "Ethnicity"])
```

Then

```
 df.loc[df.Ethnicity.isnull(), 'Ethnicity'] = \
              df.loc[df.Ethnicity.isnull(), 'Name'].map(df.loc[df.Ethnicity.notnull()] \
                .set_index('Name')['Ethnicity'])
```

Output:

```
    Name    Age Ethnicity
0   Sam     17  E
1   Chris   0   B
2   Tom     19  P
3   Sam     22  E
4   Chris   18  B
5   Tom     7   P
```

But if you are sure that the Name of NaN value will have the corresponding name always then you can use group by

```
df["Ethnicity"] = df.groupby('Name').ffill()["Ethnicity"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try sort and ffill().at last sort_index() if you want.Something like below .I have used a random df

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['a', 'c', 'f',  'a','c','f'],
    'B' :[3, 4, 2,10,3, 1],
    'C':[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 12,13,14]
  })
print(df.sort_values(by=['A','C']).ffill().sort_index())
```